# How to handle integer overflow in C

Tags: c, integer-overflow, anagram

I'm trying to create anagrams from words where answers are supposed to be for example:

The word "at" should have two anagrams.
ordeals should have 5040 anagrams.
abcdABCDabcd shoud have 29937600 anagrams.
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz should have 403291461126605635584000000 anagrams.
abcdefghijklmabcdefghijklm should have 49229914688306352000000.

My program seems to work for the first three examples but not for the last two. How can I change the program to make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

int contains(char haystack[], char needle) {
    size_t len = strlen(haystack);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned long long int f) {
    if (f == 0)
        return 1;
    return (f * factorial(f - 1));
}

int main(void) {
    char str[1000], ch;
    unsigned long long int i;
    unsigned long long int frequency = 0;
    float answer = 0;
    char visited[1000];
    int indexvisited = 0;
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    unsigned long long int nominator = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        ch = str[j];
        frequency = 0;
        if (!contains(visited, ch)) {
            for (int k = 0; str[k] != '\0'; ++k) {
                if (ch == str[k])
                    ++frequency;
            }
            printf("Frequency of %c = %lld\n", ch, frequency);
            visited[indexvisited] = ch;
            visited[++indexvisited] = '\0';
            nominator = nominator * factorial(frequency);
        }
    }
    printf("Number of anagrams = %llu\n", (factorial( i )/nominator ) );
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Do you need an exact answer or will approximate do?

Comment: "How to handle integer overflow in C?" - You don't, you avoid it at all costs under penalty of **Undefined Behaviour**.

Comment: @pmg "How to count to 26!?"

Comment: I understand that is what you meant to ask.... but I tend to answer what is asked most often :-)

Comment: Some C compilers have limited support for 128-bit integers. Try declaring your variables as `uint128_t` or `__uint128_t` and see if that helps. You will probably have to write your own function to print these values, but it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Cool, it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Even though an `unsigned long long` is pretty big, it's not completely unbounded. Its maximum value is around 1*10^19. If your source string is 26 characters long, you calculate `factorial(26)` - which is around 4*10^26, much *much* bigger than will fit in an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: Then what is a type that can fit `factorial(26)` ? Is there any ?

Comment: No, but there are libraries like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). Or maybe you can find a better algorithm ...

Comment: In C++, there are no built-in types that big. You'll need to find another way of handling it. For instance, many of the terms will cancel with those in `nominator`.

Comment: Note that the maximum value of `unsigned long long` is implementation defined.  It *could* be a 256-bit integer on some implementations, with sufficient capacity for `factorial(26)`.  I know of no implementation on which that is the case, however.  Implementations are permitted to provide extended integer types, though, and I would not be too surprised to find that one or two do provide an extended integer type large enough for `factorial(26)`.  Not that that likely helps the OP.

Comment: Fair point. I tend to forget that the "usual" sizes aren't universal. The spec guarantees that it's _at least_ 64-bits, but yes - it _could_ be bigger, or there _could_ be bigger types. There usually aren't, though.

Comment: @Chowlett `The spec guarantees that it's at least 64-bits` - I tried to look that up but could not find it. Can you add a reference to that.

Comment: @4386427: see [5.2.4.2.1 in the c11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) -- "ULLONG_MAX         18446744073709551615 // 2^64 - 1" (I added the ^ for exponentiation)

Comment: @pmg - Thanks, I missed the part `Their implementation-deﬁned values shall be equal or greater ...`

Answer (score 1):

When you need to work with ridicously large numbers you have to split things, i'd say that using a `long double` to store the root number and a `long unsigned int` to store the 10th potence would do the trick.

```
4*10^26  == ld 4, lui 26 == ld * 10^lui
```

this could be usefull for calculations, not sure tho how to represent it, it'll overflow everything but a string

Answer (score 1):

Just for the fun, here's the best I could come up with using only built-in datatypes. Instead of calculating factorials over and over (and, btw, avoid recursion for such things!), it has an "intelligent" n over k function. Note that it attempts to detect an overflow, but this is not really reliable.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef size_t AsciiCountTable[0x80];

static int countAsciiCharacters(const char *input, AsciiCountTable table)
{
    const char *c = input;
    while (*c)
    {
        if ((unsigned char)*c > 0x7f)
        {
            // not an ascii character
            return 0;
        }
        ++table[(int)*c];
        ++c;
    }
    return 1;
}

static unsigned long long nOverK(size_t n, size_t k)
{
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    size_t barrier = n - k;
    if (k > barrier) barrier = k;

    for (size_t i = n; i > barrier; --i)
    {
        result *= i;
    }
    for (size_t i = 2; i <= n - barrier; ++i)
    {
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <word>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    AsciiCountTable countTable = {0};
    if (!countAsciiCharacters(argv[1], countTable))
    {
        fputs("Only ASCII characters allowed.\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t positions = strlen(argv[1]);
    unsigned long long permutations = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 0x80; ++i)
    {
        size_t n = positions;
        size_t k = countTable[i];
        if (k > 0)
        {
            unsigned long long temp = permutations;
            permutations *= nOverK(n, k);
            if (temp > permutations)
            {
                fputs("Overflow detected.\n", stderr);
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            positions -= k;
        }
    }

    printf("permutations: %" PRIuMAX "\n", permutations);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```